# Multiplefile upload using uplodify

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to upload multiple files with title and links. And the code is :

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#divUpload').uploadify(
        {
            'uploader': 'admin/fileupload/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'admin/home-banner-list.aspx?process=fileupload',
            'multi' : 'true',
            'method' : 'POST',
            'cancelImg' :'admin/images/cancel.png',
            'folder': '../source/BannerImage',
            'queueSizeLimit' : '20',
            'fileDesc' : '*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.BMP',
            'fileExt': '*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.BMP',
            'wmode' : 'transparent',
            'onCancel':function(event,queueID,fileObj,data)
                       {
                         if(data['fileCount']==0)
                          {
                            txtboxIndex=0;
                            $('#btnUploadfile').hide();
                            $('#btnCancelUploadfile').hide();
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            txtboxIndex=txtboxIndex-1;
                          }
                       },
            'onAllComplete': function(event,data) 
                             {                             
                                jQuery('#'+divMsg).css('display','');
                                jQuery('#'+divMsg).html('Banner(s) has been uploaded successfully.').attr('class','successmsg');
                                window.setTimeout("window.location.href='admin/home-banner-list.aspx'",2000);           
                             },
            'onSelect' : function(event,queueid,fileObj)
                         {
                            $('#btnUploadfile').show(); 
                            $('#btnCancelUploadfile').show();
                         },
            'onComplete': function(event,queueID,fileObj,response,data)
                          {                         
                            if(response=='maxupload')errcnt++;
                          }
        })
    });
    function CancelUpload() 
    {        
        $('#divUpload').uploadifyClearQueue(); 
        if(jQuery('.uploadifyQueueItem').length>0)
            DisplMsg('<%= divMsg.ClientID %>','Banner(s) upload has been cancelled.','msgerror');
        window.setTimeout("window.location.href='admin/home-banner-list.aspx'",2000);
    }
    function UploadFiles()
        {                         
            var cnt='';
            var str='';    
            $('.tbxLink').each(function(index)
            {                
                 if(jQuery.trim($(this).val())!='')
                 {
                    if(!isValidURL(jQuery.trim($(this).val())))
                     {   
                        if(cnt.length ==0)
                            cnt=(index + 1);
                        else
                            cnt=cnt + ',' +(index + 1);
                     }
                 }
            });
            if(cnt.length!=0)
            {    
                alert('Please insert valid link in image#' + cnt);
                return false;
            }

          $('.txttitle').each(function(index)
          {
              cnt= $(this).attr('name').replace('txttitle','');
              str =str + ',\'' + $(this).attr('name') + '\':\'' + $(this).val() + '\'';
              str =str + ',\'' + 'tbxLink' + cnt + '\':\'' + $('#tbxLink' + cnt).val() + '\'';
              str= str + ',\'' + cnt + '\':\'' +  $('#hdnfile'+ cnt).val() + '\'';
          });
          str = str.substring(1);
          str='{' + str + '}';
          $('#divUpload').uploadifySettings('scriptData', str ,false);
          $('#divUpload').uploadifyUpload();     
       }
```

This code works file in IE but in firefox not working.
In firefox the following script is not called

'script': 'admin/home-banner-list.aspx?process=fileupload'

Comment: What errors do you get in the error console?

Comment: not getting any error. 'onAllComplete' is called and page is also redirected.

Answer (score 0):

could you try the following:

window.setTimeout("window.location.href='/admin/home-banner-list.aspx'",2000);

I have just added a '/' before 'admin'

Comment: Yes i have tried the full path : /projectname/admin/home-banner-list.aspx?process=fileupload

Answer (score 0):

Now its working...
I have change the code as follows :

$('.txttitle').each(function(index)
          {
              cnt= $(this).attr('name').replace('txttitle','');
              str =str + ',\'' + $(this).attr('name') + '\':\'' + $(this).val() + '\'';
              **str =str + ',\'' + $('#tbxLink' + cnt).attr('name') + '\':\'' + $('#tbxLink' + cnt).val() + '\'';**
              str= str + ',\'' + cnt + '\':\'' +  $('#hdnfile'+ cnt).val() + '\'';
          });

Answer (score 0):

```
'onAllComplete' do not called when 'multi'=>true.
```